# VMware stuck in shutting down Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, vmware, macbook, shutdown

I use VMware with Windows XP on MacBook and it is stuck on Windows Shutting down-and I can't do anything. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough ram to run VMware? 2G is the basic requirement for it.It maybe caused by the slow response of your computer.If you want to stop it anyway, end the process directly, it may damage your  vmware file.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with 3 Gb ram. I found [an article](http://www.aumha.org/win5/a/shtdwnxp.htm). I've just decided to restart my virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

My XP guest often hangs (or stalls, but I get impatient) before shutting down until I manually kill the batch file I leave running (it loops every 3 sec to watch for Windows commands from the OS-X host).  This is true of XP generally, not necessarily running as a VM, though it may be a little quicker as the native OS than as a VM, to kill off tasks that ignore its polite requests.

Is anything running persistently in your XP guest?